# special characters in url not working as expected tableau

Tags: tableau-api, urlencode

I am seeing a weird issue when passing special characters in the url.

some of my keys in the URL have `space` like for example `County Unique` and I also have some filters which have values `N/A`

As per the documentation (https://kb.tableau.com/articles/issue/special-characters-in-url-parameters) when I escape the special characters and encode the url, the filters that have values like `Portage (OH)` do not work but filters which have values like `N/A work`, so if my url has the encoded value for `Portage (OH) & N/A`, the filter does not load with `Portage (OH)` selected but it does load with `N/A` selected. Here is a example url

`&Operator=Chesapeake%2CMountaineer%5C%20Keystone%2CNorthwood%5C%20Energy%2CUS%5C%20Energy&Basin=Utica&State=Ohio&County%5C%20Unique=Portage%5C%20%5C%28OH%5C%29&Field=%2CRootstown%2CSuffield%2CWindham&Formation=Other%2CPoint%5C%20Pleasant&First%5C%20Production%5C%20Year=2011%2C2013%2CN%5C%2FA&Well%5C%20type=Gas%2COil&LastWellStatusCalc=2%5C.%5C%20DUC%2C4%5C.%5C%20Producing%2C5%5C.%5C%20Inactive%2C6%5C.%5C%20Plugged&Well%5C%20name=ASHER%5C%20%5C%20%5C%20%5C%20%5C%20PORT2AHSU%5C%20%5C%283413324430%5C%29%2CFRAME%5C%20UNIT%5C%20%5C%20%5C%20%5C%20%5C%201H%5C%20%5C%283413324478%5C%29%2CFRAME%5C%20UNIT%5C%20%5C%20%5C%20%5C%20%5C%202H%5C%20%5C%283413324477%5C%29%2CHOSEY%5C%20POR%5C%20%5C%20%5C%20%5C%20%5C%206H%5C-X%5C%20%5C%283413324420%5C%29%2CSEKEL%5C%20UNIT%5C%20%5C%20%5C%20%5C%20%5C%201H%5C%20%5C%283413324473%5C%29%2CSOINSKI%5C%2099%5C-04%5C-06%5C%20%5C%20%5C%20%5C%20%5C%20201%5C%20%5C%283413324440%5C%29%2CSOINSKI%5C%2099%5C-04%5C-06%5C%20%5C%20%5C%20%5C%20%5C%20202%5C%20%5C%283413324441%5C%29%2CSOINSKI%5C%20211%5C-214%5C%20%5C%20%5C%20%5C%20%5C%20211%5C%20%5C%283413324446%5C%29%2CSOINSKI%5C%20211%5C-214%5C%20%5C%20%5C%20%5C%20%5C%20212%5C%20%5C%283413324444%5C%29%2CSOINSKI%5C%20211%5C-214%5C%20%5C%20%5C%20%5C%20%5C%20213%5C%20%5C%283413324443%5C%29`

Now, if I keep the keys as is and don't replace the space in keys to `%5C%20`, the filters work with values like `Portage (OH)` but values like `N/A` do not work anymore.

Can any one please help, as to what I am doing wrong. I need to pass values which have special characters in filter values as well as my keys have a `space` in names.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Check under `URL action` there is a option called `URL Encode Data Values`.

Additionally if `Null` (**assuming N/A is null**) values are giving you issues, syntax of escaping null:

```
&dim1=~~null~
```

Comment: Hi @r.ruckus, many thanks for your reply, i will try this. but something i am unable to understand is, if i encode my keys certain condition works and if i don't then some other condition works :(

Comment: @opensource-developer check this link: https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/embed_filter_add.htm. When you are embedding multiple values for filter, put it in the value tag as seen under the heading  'Filter on multiple fields' in the link above.